# Best way to migrate directories to SVN with history

Tags: svn

I've weekly backups of source directories and want to migrate to SVN.

While moving to SVN I want to retain the evolution of the source directories to build up the SVN histories of the source tree.

Let me explain this through an example:

```
my_project_2011_02_01.zip
my_project_2011_02_13.zip
my_project_2011_02_18.zip
my_project_2011_02_23.zip
...
```

my task:

- extract the first version `my_project_2011_02_01.zip` and add this to SVN under my_project.
- Now I want to extract `my_project_2011_02_13.zip` and add the new files, overwrite the changed files and remove the files that aren't in the source tree anymore.

I use the svn client tortoisesvn.

which way is the best / most comfortable way to achieve this?

Comment: Is it possible to TortoiseSVN->Delete the entire content of the project folder without committing, copy the newer content to it and then committing. will this replace the files that exists earlier in the old project folder and delete the other files that don't exist any more in the new project folder?

Comment: I don't know the behavior of TortoiseSVN, but it should work that way.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a batch script which basically does the following steps for each zip file:

1. svn rm * (in project folder)
2. extract zip and copy in project folder
3. svn add --force .  (in project folder)
4. svn commit . -m "version of project snapshot" (in project folder)

Comment: Tortoise SVN has no command line interface. I use [Slik SVN](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download) on Windows when I need to do Subversion stuff from the command line.

Comment: You mean [this](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html)? That looks even less user-friendly than the standard SVN CLI. =) I stand by my recommendation of Slik SVN.

Comment: I can of course use svn command line client on cygwin. but it must cope with files that are deleted in newer version of the project folder.

Comment: I meant the default windows command shell. Just install the Subversion client somewhere in your $PATH and put the above commands in a batch file. For linux users the equivalent would be a bash script of course.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the only way would be to start by checking in the first week's archive.  Next, overwrite the local files with the second week's archive and check in those changes.  Repeat until all archives are checked in.

The main annoyance with this, other than the amount of time it will take, is that svn will often be unable to auto-resolve conflicts.  In your case, you would simply choose the latest version to win, but it will likely add more time to the process.

Is there any reason why you would need the full history?  In this situation I would be inclined to only check in the latest version, and not worry about the history to this point. Or perhaps only check in archives related to major releases.

Edit: To handle deletes, you would need to delete the files on your hard drive first, then unzip the next archive.  The annoying part is that you need to keep the .svn folders so svn can track which files are different and which were added or removed.

Comment: Your approach does not delete files not existing in newer versions.
And as far as i can see there should be no problems with conflicts.

Comment: I would really like to go this route and do it only for some milestones. But I need a way delete the files that don't exist anymore like Alp said.